Component not re-rendering after state update
I'm a VueJS newbie and am trying to use Pinia + VueJS 3, where I react to a WebSocket updates (via a Supabase SDK) and re-render a component tree as a result. I have a list of players, where each one can vote (it's a planning poker app). When a new player arrives, I update the players list in the Pinia store, and the player is rendered. When a player votes, I also have an updated list of players and re-assign the players list and would expect the player's card status to change, but it doesn't.
I suspect I'm missing something in the way I render the individual player cards. I tried to re-write the code in a few different ways (passing the player, passing just the id and then looking it up in the store, etc.,), but it doesn't work.
I think I'm missing something about the update mechanism, but unsure what else it could be. Any help would be really appreciated!
// Pinia store
export const useGameStore = defineStore('gameStore', () => {
  const currentPlayer = ref<Player>({
    name: generateSlug(1),
    isAdmin: false
  });
  const players = ref<Player[]>([]);
  const channel = ref<RealtimeChannel>(null);
  const currentGameId = ref<string>(null);

  function subscribeToGameUpdates(channel: RealtimeChannel) {
    channel.on('presence', { event: 'sync' }, () => {
      players.value = getCurrentPlayers(channel);
    }).on('presence', { event: 'join' }, () => {
      players.value = getCurrentPlayers(channel);
    }).on('presence', { event: 'leave' }, () => {
      players.value = getCurrentPlayers(channel);
    }).subscribe();
  }

  async function startGame() {
    const slug = generateSlug();
    await joinGame(slug);
  }

  async function joinGame(id: string) {
    const newChannel = getRoom(id);
    joinRoom(newChannel);
    subscribeToGameUpdates(newChannel);
    currentGameId.value = id;

    currentPlayer.value = { ...currentPlayer.value, isAdmin: true };

    channel.value = newChannel;
    players.value = getCurrentPlayers(newChannel);
    await updateSelfState(currentPlayer.value, newChannel);
  }

  async function vote(selectedCard: Card) {
    await updateSelfState({ ...currentPlayer.value, selectedCardValue: selectedCard.value }, channel.value);
  }


  return {
    startGame,
    joinGame,
    vote,

    currentPlayer,
    players,
    currentGameId
  };
});

// Players list

<script setup lang="ts">

import PlayerAvatar from './PlayerAvatar.vue';

import { useGameStore } from '../stores/GameStore';
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

const gameStore = useGameStore()
const { players } = storeToRefs(gameStore);

</script>

<template>
  <div class="opponents-root">
    <PlayerAvatar v-for="(player, index) in players" :player-name="player.name" :key="index" />
  </div>

</template>

<style scoped>
.opponents-root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
}
</style>

// Player card

<script setup lang="ts">

import { useGameStore } from '../stores/GameStore';
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

const {playerName} = defineProps<{
  playerName: string
}>()

const gameStore = useGameStore()
const { players, currentPlayer } = storeToRefs(gameStore);
const player = [...players.value, currentPlayer.value].find(x => x.name === playerName)

// A breakpoint put here gets hit during the initial card render, but not after one of the players votes.
const isVoting = player.selectedCardValue === undefined

</script>

<template>
  <div class="player-root">
    <div class="player-glyph">{{isVoting ? '⌛' : '✅'}}</div>
    <div class="player-name">{{player.name}}</div>
  </div>
</template>


const player = [...players.value - this is the problem, probably the only one. You disable reactivity by eagerly accessing ref value. It's supposed to be a computed. So is isVoting

Thanks, that was it! When I wrap these lines as computed properties, it works :-)
const player = computed(() => [...players.value, currentPlayer.value].find(x => x.name === playerName)) const isVoting = computed(() => player.value.selectedCardValue === undefined)
